# ipython notebook nbconvert - how to remove red 'out[N]' text in top left hand corner of cell output?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using nbconvert to produce something as close as possible to a polished journal article.

I have successfully hidden input code using a custom nbconvert template. The doc is now looking very nice.

But I don't know how to suppress the bright red 'out[x]' statement in the top left corner of the output cells. Anyone know of any settings or hacks that are able to remove this also ?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version of IPython you are using, there are more or less hackish ways to remove the Out[ ] prompts.

### IPython 1.x

Assuming that you use the `latex_article` base, a custom template (sphinx_template.tplx) with removed input blocks could look like

```
((* extends 'latex_article.tplx' *))
((* block input *))
((* endblock input *))
((* block output_group *))
   % Add remainer of the document contents below.
   ((* for output in cell.outputs *))
        ((( render_output(output) )))
   ((* endfor *))
((* endblock *))
```

To finally remove the prompt, you need to use the `simple` mode of the Sphinx style, hence use it like 
`ipython nbconvert --to latex --SphinxTransformer.output_style=simple --template=sphinx_template.tplx test.ipynb`

### IPython Master

In IPython master additional cell styles have been added, see e.g. [PR4112](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4112).
How to use these styles is shown e.g. in [example1](https://github.com/ipython/nbconvert-examples/tree/master/latex_cell_style) and [examples2](https://github.com/ipython/nbconvert-examples/tree/master/custom_latex_cell_style).

To sum up, here the template (bw_python.tplx) could look like (with inputs)

```
((= This line selects the cell style. =))
((* set cell_style = 'style_bw_python.tplx' *))

((= This line inherits from the built in template that you want to use. =))
((* extends 'latex_article.tplx' *))
```

This is used without additional options, hence
`ipython nbconvert --to=latex --template=bw_python.tplx test.ipynb`

Comment: Great. Thanks. I have ipython master, and am using a modified version of the citations template in the nbconvert_examples/citations repo, with some lines added to remove input code for figures. So just needed to add ((* set cell_style = 'style_bw_python.tplx' *)) as above. Direct notebook-to-paper workflow is now almost in place...

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, you may accept it, to finalize this question.

Answer (score 5):

`%%HTML
<style>
div.prompt {display:none}
</style>`

This will hide both In and Out prompts

Note that this is only in your browser, the notebook itself isn't modified of course, and `nbconvert` will work just the same as before.

In case you want this in the `nbconvert`ed code as well, just put the `<style>div.prompt {display:none}</style>` in a Raw NBConvert cell.

Comment: This doesn't work in jupyter lab, any ideas on how to hide it in jupyter lab?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IPython.display.display` to display the values. This prevents the cell from having output. In addition, with the `%%capture` magic command you can prevent any remaining output (warnings, errors, etc.) from being rendered.

And for the exporter, you can pass `exclude_input=True` to hide all input cells.

An example:

```py
%%capture --no-display

import logging
from IPython.display import display

logging.warning("this warning is captured and not displayed")
display(1+1)
```

will display `2` *without* any `Out[1]` or warnings.

You can then export the notebook without any of the input cells with:

```py
nbconvert.export(exporter, 'notebook.ipynb', exclude_input=True)
```