# remove nbconvert --to html 'in' and 'out' prompts based on cell metadata

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to remove the red and blue 'In' and 'Out' prompts when running `nbconvert --to html`, based on cell metadata. With cell metadata such as:

```
{'cell_tags': {'cutcode_html': true}}
```

The following sucessfully removes the `'In'` prompt:

```
{% block input_group %}
 {% if cell['metadata'].get('cell_tags',{}).get('cutcode_html','') == True -%}
  <div></div>
 {% else %}
  {{ super() }}
 {% endif %}
{% endblock input_group %}
```

I'd like to do the equivalent thing for the output prompt.

There has been discussion of how to do this for [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184994/ipython-notebook-nbconvert-how-to-remove-red-outn-text-in-top-left-hand-co), but I can't figure out how to do it for HTML.

The `output_prompt` blocks for HTML don't appear to do anything, and whenever I try to make slightly modified versions of the primary templates, they won't load properly.

Comment: Do you want to remove just the prompts or the whole input and output group, respectively? The input_group you showed should treat the whole input whereas the output_group treats the whole output, see [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/nbconvert/templates/skeleton/null.tpl)

Comment: I want to remove the whole input and just the prompt for the output. So the result should for example just be a rendered image from an 'IPython.display.Image()' call. Doing this with the metadata allows me to selectively specify when I want to embed an image just as an image (I don't like the file dependency of markdown images), and when I want to demonstrate code usage with inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, changing the output prompt is a bit more demanding because if you simply override the `block output` by extending the *full.tpl* you have to include a `super()` call to include the outputs. Unfortunately, the parent block (included by the super call) will add the *Out* prompt again and will mess up the html.

To get something similar to what you want, I did the following. (Note, I haven't included a complete template here, because the templates are currently changing due to the implementation of the v4 notebook format. Here, I'm using IPython 2.3)

1. Copy the *base.tpl* e.g. *noprompt.tpl*
2. As this template cannot be used directly, add the code from the *full.tpl* to *noprompt.tpl*
3. change the `block input_group` as you showed
4. change the `block output` to something like

   ```
   {% block output %}
   <div class="output_area">
   {%- if cell['metadata'].get('cell_tags',{}).get('cutcode_html','') != True and output.output_type == 'pyout' -%}
   <div class="prompt output_prompt">
   Out[{{ cell.prompt_number }}]:
   {%- else -%}
   <div class="prompt">
   {%- endif -%}
   </div>
   {{ super() }}
   </div>
   {% endblock output %}
   ```

With this I could convert a notebook with the prompts conditionally removed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line option `--no-prompt`

```
nbconvert --to html --no-prompt
```