# How Can I Map IPython/Jupyter Cell Level Metadata Elements to Custom Styled HTML Components Using nbconvert?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a set of notebooks with metadata elements set at the cell level to define different sorts of activity.

For example, in the following `.ipynb` file there is a metadata element `commentate` set to `true` that is dynamically styled using a custom notebook extension to show a coloured background.

[image: Example styled IPython notebook cell]

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "#Header\n",
    "\n",
    "..and some markdown."
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {
    "commentate": true
   },
   "source": [
    "Metadata styled markdown."
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.4.0"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 0
}
```

I would like to generate a correspondingly styled HTML version of this notebook using `nbconvert`.

Is there a way I can map `ipynb` cell level metadata elements onto a CSS class and then associate a custom CSS file with, or embed custom CSS elements in, the generated HTML file?

Alternatively, is there a simple pattern for translating cell level metadata attributes/values to associated custom styled elements in converted HTML?

Comment: You can make the custom template metadata-aware as shown e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26962524/2870069) and use this conditional to embed your markdown in some html class which gets formatted by CSS.

Comment: Okay - thanks; where do the base templates live? And where should custom templates go? Is there any useful guidance on using custom templates, how to extend/complement base ones, etc? I couldn't find anything that helped me working from a standing start?

Comment: The base templates are found in the nbconvert directory and you can put your custom templates wherever you want. There are some questions here on SO related to custom templates and there is [this repo](https://github.com/ipython/nbconvert-examples) with some examples.