# Toggle specific input cell in nbconvert --to latex

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2, jupyter-notebook

I've seen this question alluded to a couple times on Github and on SO (specifically, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184994/ipython-notebook-nbconvert-how-to-remove-red-outn-text-in-top-left-hand-co)), but I'm having a hard time coming up with a good solution.

I have a report that I have prepared using an IPython notebook.  Many of the input cells are function definitions that the intended reader won't care about.  I'm looking for a way to selectively render specific "input" cells in the latex output of nbconvert.  I'm just getting familiar with the jinja2 templating engine, and I'm pretty green with the whole thing.

Is there any way to use the reveal.js toolbar to set the cells I would like to render, and then use Jinja2 to render them?  something like

```
% Disable input cells
((* block input_group *))
    if cell_type =="code" and metadata['slideshow'] == 'slide':
        render cell

((* endblock input_group *))
```