# Hide ipython notebook prompt

Tags: python, css, ipython, jupyter-notebook

How can I hide the "In [*]:" prompts on the left side of input cells in ipython notebooks, as shown below? [image]

Edit:  The question asked in [ipython notebook nbconvert - how to remove red 'out[N]' text in top left hand corner of cell output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184994/ipython-notebook-nbconvert-how-to-remove-red-outn-text-in-top-left-hand-co) is not the same as the question that is asked here. Here I want to hide the cell numbers in the browser itself, rather than in the output from nbconvert. However, one of the [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30234937/805357) in that question does solve my issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ipython notebook nbconvert - how to remove red 'out\[N\]' text in top left hand corner of cell output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184994/ipython-notebook-nbconvert-how-to-remove-red-outn-text-in-top-left-hand-co)

Answer (score 10):

This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30234937/805357 .Putting the following code in a cell hides the cell numbers.

```
%%HTML
<style>
div.prompt {display:none}
</style>
```